# Troouble in inserting value in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a DB (using phpmyadmin). I want to enter data in the master table but the problem is I want to take the details from the user in two different HTML pages.

If I am able to store data from htmlpage1 into the DB the next HTML page doesn't store any data.

I have tried;

1 - using where command in the second page. no help.
2 - tried to save data into variables and store all the data together when I have it from htmlpage2 as well.

NOTE:

HTML page 1 has a submit button "register"
HTML page 2 has a submit button "submit"

here is the code.;

```
<?php
session_start();
$enrollment = "";
$username = "";
$email = "";
$password = "";
$fathername = "";
$dateofbirth = "";
$course = "";
$contact = "";
$gender = "";
$address = "";
$city = "";
$state = "";
$country = "";
$tenth = "";
$twth = "";
$ug = "";
$pg = "";
$phd = "";
$sem1 = "";
$sem2 = "";
$sem3 = "";
$sem4 = "";
$train1 = "";
$train2 = "";
$ts1 = "";
$ts2 = "";
$ts3 = "";
$errors = array();


$db= mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'spaarc');


if (isset($_POST['register'])){
        $enrollment = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['enrollment']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['sname']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
        $fathername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fname']);
        $dateofbirth = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['dob']);
        $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['course']);
        $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['contact']);
        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gender']);
        $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['address']);
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['city']);
        $pin = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['pincode']);
        $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['state']);
        $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['country']);

        if (empty($username)){
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");
        }
        if (empty($email)){
            array_push($errors, "Email is required");
        }
        if (empty($password)){
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
        }
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $tenth = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['ClassX_Percentage']);
        $twth = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['ClassXII_Percentage']);
        $ug = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Graduation_Percentage']);
        $pg = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Masters_Percentage']);
        $phd = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['PhD_Percentage']);
        $sem1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['topic1']);
        $sem2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['topic2']);
        $sem3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['topic3']);
        $sem4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['topic4']);
        $train1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['train1']);
        $train2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['train2']);
        $ts1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['sub']);
        $ts2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['prog']);
        $ts3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cer']);

        if (empty($ts1)){
            array_push($errors, "ts is required");
        }
        if (empty($ts2)){
            array_push($errors, "ts is required");
        }
        if (empty($ts3)){
            array_push($errors, "ts is required");
        }   
        if (count($errors)==0){
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql="INSERT INTO studetails (enrollment, name, email, password, fname, dob, course, contact, gender, address, city, pin, state, country, tenth, twth, ug, pg, phd, sem1, sem2, sem3, sem4, train1, train2, ts1, ts2, ts3) VALUES ('$enrollment','$username', '$email', '$password','$fathername','$dateofbirth','$course','$contact','$gender','$address','$city','$pin','$state','$country','$tenth','$twth','$ug','$pg','$phd','$sem1','$sem2','$sem3','$sem4','$train1','$train1','$ts1','$ts2','$ts3')";
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            $_SESSION['sname'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: preview.php');
        }
}
?>
```

NOTE:

```
$enrollment = "";
$username = "";
$email = "";
$password = "";
$fathername = "";
$dateofbirth = "";
$course = "";
$contact = "";
$gender = "";
$address = "";
$city = "";
$state = "";
$country = "";
```

this is to be stored from HTML page1
and the rest from HTML page2

And what values in the DB should accept NULL in this condition??

Comment: Yikes `md5()`!  Please research this process more.  And prepared statements while you are at it.  Your question is Unclear to me.  Do you want to do an INSERT and then later an UPDATE?

Comment: Hello! Do you enter all value in two different table  i do not undersatnd